# Trouble setting Content Security Policy correctly for local websocket server on a different port

Tags: express, http, content-security-policy

I am developing an webapp which includes pulling a file from https://immersive-web.github.io/webxr-input-profiles/... and connecting to a local websocket server on the same host (wss://localhost:9001).  I have tried a few different combinations of setting the http header to allow this cross communication to no avail.

```
res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy',
  "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://localhost:* https://immersive-web.github.io/ ; content-src wss://localhost:*");
```

In chrome, I get these errors:

[image]

I did confirm that the http headers are being set:

[image]

I figured I have a syntax error somewhere or I am miss understanding the CSP configuration.  What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  I had to set the Content-Security-Policy in two places: 1) index.html and 2) express.js middleware code.

The master angular index.html I set:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://*.github.io wss: ;"
```

> 

And now in my node.js code, I added

```
  res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy',
  "connect-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://*.github.io wss: ; default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
```

I first was just setting in the index.html file.  Now it is working.